# I am getting that error "Creating default object from empty value ". Can anyone help me?

Tags: php, laravel

this is my blade. Adding product is working but i am getting error on update page.

```
@extends('base')
@section('form')

<div class="col-md-12">
    <h2>Ürün Düzenle</h2>
    <div align="right">
        <a href="{{route('urunler')}}">
            <button class="btn btn-success">Geri</button>
        </a>
        <br> <br>
    </div>
    <form action="{{route('arabaduzenlepost',['id'=>$products ?? 'id'])}}"   method="POST">
        @csrf
        <select name="category_id">
            <option selected="" value="default">Lütfen Kategori Seçiniz</option>
            <option value="1">Sedan</option>
            <option value="2">Hatchback</option>
            <option value="3">Station Wagon</option>
        </select>
        </select>
        <input name="adi" type="text" value="{{ $products ?? 'name' }}" >
        <input name="renk" id="renk" type="text" value="{{ $products ?? 'color' }}">
        <input name="km" type="text" value="{{ $products ?? 'km' }}">
        <input name="fiyat" id="fiyat" type="text" value="{{ $products ?? 'price' }}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn--lg btn--alt-color" style="float:right;">DÜZENLE
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

this is my controller. I want to update the product when you click the update button. And I want the fields to be full.

```
public  function arabaduzenlepost(Request $request){
    $id = $request->id;
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $product->name = $request->input('adi');
    $product->color = $request->input('renk');
    $product->km = $request->input('km');
    $product->price = $request->input('fiyat');
    $product->save();

    return redirect()->action('ArabaController@urunler');   }
```

this is my database

```
 Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('color');
        $table->string('km');
        $table->string('price');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        $table->timestamps();
```

Answer (score 0):

update your blade file

```php
@extends('base')
@section('form')

<div class="col-md-12">
    <h2>Ürün Düzenle</h2>
    <div align="right">
        <a href="{{route('urunler')}}">
            <button class="btn btn-success">Geri</button>
        </a>
        <br> <br>
    </div>
    <form action="{{route('arabaduzenlepost',$products->id)}}"   method="POST">
        @csrf
        <select name="category_id">
            <option selected="" value="default">Lütfen Kategori Seçiniz</option>
            <option value="1">Sedan</option>
            <option value="2">Hatchback</option>
            <option value="3">Station Wagon</option>
        </select>
        </select>
        <input name="adi" type="text" value="{{ $products->name }}" >
        <input name="renk" id="renk" type="text" value="{{ $products->color }}">
        <input name="km" type="text" value="{{ $products->km }}">
        <input name="fiyat" id="fiyat" type="text" value="{{ $products->price }}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn--lg btn--alt-color" style="float:right;">DÜZENLE
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

in php `??` means null-coalesce

ref link https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op

Comment: I updated blade but now i am getting an error "undefined variable:products"

Comment: then define that

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form action="{{route('arabaduzenlepost',['id'=>$products ?? 'id'])}}"   method="POST">
@csrf
```

Just change this to

```
<form action="{{route('arabaduzenlepost',$products->id)}}"method="post">
{{method_field('PUT')}}
{{csrf_field()}}
```